# How to save custom frontend form to database in Magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, database, frontend

How to save custom frontend form to database in Magento2.2.5?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You have created a frontend form or need the whole code including form creation?

Comment: I have created my form but I am not able to submit my values to db.

Comment: see my answer i have used this already in my form and its working for me.

Comment: Okay i will check it.. and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the form data using the controller :

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Customer;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    protected $session;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
        )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

            //$resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            //$resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Helpdesk'));
            //return $resultPage;
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

            $model = $this->_objectManager->create('VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ModelName');
            $model->setData($data);
            try {
                $model->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The Data has been saved.'));
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the Data.'));
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: can you share me your full code.

Comment: The data's are inserted successfully..thanks